# Facebook Post To Wall Photos - Separated View on Fan's Wall Page

Tags: php, facebook

I use that kind of code for my Post Cron to Facebook script (using it for my fanpage):

```
if($sch['status_type'] == 'photo')
{
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $args = array();
    $args['message'] = $sch['status_message'];
    $args['image'] = '@'.realpath($sch['photo_url']);
    $args['access_token'] = $sch['access_token'];

    try
    {
        $data = $facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos', 'post', $args);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the $album_id is my fanpage wall photos album ID, but when the script posts a photo to Wall Photos - on my friends wall it looks like "Fanpage added 2 more photos to Wall Photos".
Is it possible the uploaded photos to be separated individually?

Thank you!

Comment: i think you have to all images in an array then pass it to post var